# Building a web-based iphone/ipad simulator/emulator

Tags: web-applications, mobile, mobile-safari, cross-browser

I am tempted to ask you, what would it entail to build a web based iphone/ipad simulator/emulator that actually represents the way iphones and ipads display pages accurately?

It would require the webkit mobile engine, yes of course, or a copy of it - though that can get dead exhausting to replicate, if even possible.

So this brings me to the core of my question. Is it possible from a programming standpoint to 'port' the webkit mobile engine to a web-based environment/website so that users from all over the world, regardless of the browser they're using, can witness/experience/see the rendering of pages through the eyes of an iphone/ipad with the proper webkit mobile engine?

Cheers
G.Campos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After non-stop searching and asking around, I was unable to find evidence that this would be easy let alone possible to implement. I guess this explains why it hasn't been done before.

bummer =(

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but maybe http://www.pieceable.com/viewer is what you want. It's a wev-viewer which allows you to see your iphone app in browser. For example http://three20.info/ uses it to demonstrate possibilities.

Comment: Looks very interesting. Pieceable COULD work but their model is limited by their 'simultaneous' viewers plan/pricing model. I'll get in touch with them and see what's up. I would still like to know how they are able to 'play' OS apps online for everyone to see